# when i run a code it gives me an indentation error, why

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

When i compile this code, it gives me an error right there...

```
import pygame, sys, random, time

check_errors=pygame.init()

if check_errors[1]!=0:
    print("(!) Had {0} initializing errors, exiting...".format(check_errors[1]))
    sys.exit(-1) #ON this line  says:IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
else:
    print("(+) PyGame successfully initialized!")
```

I tried some stuff but cant make it work, im a newbee as you can see.
edit: that wasnt a problem i misstyped it...

Comment: Check your first line. It's ` import pygame, sys, random, time` instead of `import pygame, sys, random, time`

Answer (score 0):

You have a " " before the import line 1.